# Path offset when added as action to sprite

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an `SKSpriteNode` (Red Square) that I am trying to get to follow a `CGPath`. The start coordinate of the path (or the first point) is the origin of the Red Square which is [100, 50]. This coordinated is in the coordinate system of the `SKView` as thats what the Red Square is positioned in.

When I set up a simple path:

```
CGPoint newPosition = [redSquare position];
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, newPosition.x, newPosition.y);

SKAction *pathAction = [SKAction followPath:path duration:5];
[[self zombie] runAction:pathAction];
```

And run in the simulator the zombie (Green Square [0,0], which is parented to the Red Square). This is obviously adding the path in the Red Squares coordinate system as its offset by exactly the same amount as the Red Square is from the `SKView` origin.

[image]

My thinking was that I could use `SKView` `convertPointFromView` but this does not seem to be doing the right thing, if anything it offsets the zombie more in the wrong direction.

## EDIT:

If I un-parent the zombie from the Red Square (and parent it to the SKView i.e. self) then the path positions the Zombie correctly, just curious for future reference if there is a way to compensate for this offset, besides doing the parent offset manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the offset just use the extended version of followPath action and pass NO for the offset parameter:

```
+ (SKAction *)followPath:(CGPathRef)path asOffset:(BOOL)offset orientToPath:(BOOL)orient duration:(NSTimeInterval)sec
```

Because in the short version you are using:

```
+ (SKAction *)followPath:(CGPathRef)path duration:(NSTimeInterval)sec
```

offset is set to YES by default.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_16)